# Runtime error: Cannot set while device is active in this process

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I'm trying to implement a separable convolution filter using CUDA as part of a bigger application I'm working on. My code has multiple CUDA kernels which are called one after the other (each performing one stage of the process). The problem is I keep getting this weird error and I'm not sure what exactly does it mean or what is causing it. I also can't find anything about it on the Internet except a couple of Stack Overflow questions related to OpenGL and CUDA interoperability (which I'm not doing, i.e. I'm not using OpenGL at all).

Can someone please explain to me why such an error may occur?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the error string for cudaErrorSetOnActiveProcess. This error is returned if one of the interop SetDevice functions is called after the primary context has been initialized. If you are on Windows and have Nsight Visual Studio Edition you can run a CUDA trace and in the CUDA Runtime API Calls page filter on kernels with errors. If you enable call stack on error in the Activity you will be able to jump to the function causing the error. Can you post your OS info, driver version, runtime version, toolkit version, and a minimal reproducible?

Comment: Provide us the code lines which cause the error. Comment out your code, and progressively open the lines till getting the error..